# Smartcard for windows 7

Tags: bitlocker, smartcard

I am encrypting my hard drive using bitlocker, there is an option to unlock drive using smartcard. I checked couple of shopping sites all I found is smart card readers wondering where do I get card? What if I lose smartcard will I lose my hard drive? Is it reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card) should answer most of your questions about what a smart card is and how they work. [Here](http://www.smartcardsource.com/) is an example of a place to purchase them.